# Determining number of lattice paths

Tags: combinatorics

**Question:**

Determine the number of lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(6,6)$ that take steps in $ \{\ (1,0) , (0,1) \}\ $ that do not go through the point $(3,3)$.

I'm not sure what my professor means by the "that take steps in" because these steps imply that he walks backwards. What does he mean?

I know how to find the amount of lattice paths from one end to another by simply doing $x+y $ choose $x \text{ or } y$. But what do I do when a point is excluded?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The easiest way is to find the number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(6,6)$, then subtract those that go through $(3,3)$.  You say you can do the first, then find the number of ways to get from $(0,0)$ to $(3,3)$.  For each one of those, how many ways are there to get from $(3,3)$ to $(6,6)?$

Comment: There are 6 choose 3 ways to get to $(3,3)$. There are equally many ways to go from $(3,3)$ to $(6,6)$. Would I subtract 6 choose 3 from 12 choose 6?

Comment: No, because for each way you get to $(3,3)$ you have $6 \choose 3$ ways to complete the path.  You need to multiply them, then subtract.

Comment: Do you mean to say that I say: $ 6 \choose 3 $ $\cdot$ $ 6 \choose 3$ $-$ $12 \choose 6 $?

Comment: The other way around, but yes.  Your expression will be negative.

Comment: Why is my expression negative? I get 524?

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=924+-+20%5E2

Comment: Note that 20 = $ 6 \choose 3$ and 924  = $12 \choose 6$

Comment: Because the way you wrote it was $20 \cdot 20 - 924=-524$  Your Alpha link is the other way around.  I agree with $524$

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I believe the problem is trying to say a valid move is to increase either the first or second coordinate by $1$.  In other words, from $(3,2)$, you could go to $(4,2)$ or $(3,3)$.

As for how to solve it, can you figure out how many paths do go through $(3,3)$ and exclude them?

Answer (score 0):

The length of the word is (6,6) = 6+6 = 12. Calculate all the possibility from (0,0) to (6,6) with the formula or (12!/6!(12-6)! = 924.
Because you may not go through (3,3) then calculate from (0,0) to (3,3). (Now is the length of the word 6 because (3,3) = 3+3 or 6. so (6!/3!(6-3)! = 20. But the length from (3,3) to (6,6) is equal from (0,0) to (3,3) so you get 20*20 or 400. Then you have the total possibilities that are 924 - 400 = 524 possibilities from (0,0) - (6,6) without go through (3,3). That is your answer: 524